# How to recover data after "Safely remove drive" applied on ext4 drive under Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, hard-drive, ext4, safely-remove-hardware

## The story

I have an external harddisk that has been formatted for use with Linux. Unfortunately I inserted this disk in a Windows computer. Immediately after that it became corrupted. I have used external disks on Windows and Linux interchangeably without any problems for disks that are formatted with NTFS. However, this time I was caught off-guard with ext4.

## The harddisk

This concerns an external 4TB USB external harddisk with rotational disks that was formatted on Linux with GPT partition and ext4 filesystem. It contains only one partition. The disk contains somewhere between 500 GB and 2000 GB of data. The disk does not use an additional power source other than the USB cable that is used for both data and power. The harddisk is less than a year old, is used only occasionally and has always worked without any problems until this week.

## The exact cause

Here's the timeline:

- I connected the ext4 formatted USB external harddisk to a Windows 11 computer (mistake #1)
- Windows explorer showed an empty disk
- I did a "safely remove drive" (mistake #2)
- I physically disconnected the harddisk
- I connected the harddisk to a Linux Mint computer
- Linux now also showed an empty harddisk in the file manager

## What have a tried in order to resolve this issue?

- I tried to minimize invasive operations as much as possible
- I ran fsck.ext4 with the "-n" option (see below)
- I did research on google on how to recover from "safely remove drive" on an ext4 formatted disk within Windows
- I tried to understand the "safely remove drive" feature under Windows
- I tried using software that can diagnose harddisks
- I copied the partition to another identical disk using dd command, but it said "disk full" after 3.9 TB have been copied. Going to look for a bigger disk.

## CLI outputs

```
stack@exchange:~$ sudo lsblk  /dev/sdd
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdd      8:48   0  3,7T  0 disk 
└─sdd1   8:49   0  3,7T  0 part /home/stack/classes
```

```
stack@exchange:~$ sudo lsblk  -f  /dev/sdd
NAME   FSTYPE LABEL           UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
sdd                                                                               
└─sdd1 ext4   maxtor_classes b5169f43-d688-4f8d-a659-3d030eaeb7df    3,4T     0% /home/stack/classes
```

```
stack@exchange:~$ sudo blkid /dev/sdd  /dev/sdd1
/dev/sdd: PTUUID="a06d421e-6ccd-4993-b9b7-993c3a5ae2b0" PTTYPE="gpt"
/dev/sdd1: LABEL="maxtor_classes" UUID="b5169f43-d688-4f8d-a659-3d030eaeb7df" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="b27c013b-4a40-4900-4cb8-a362727c5fc3"
```

```
stack@exchange:~$ sudo mount | egrep sdd 
/dev/sdd1 on /home/stack/classes type ext4 (rw,relatime)
```

```
stack@exchange:~$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdd  /dev/sdd1
Disk /dev/sdd: 3,65 TiB, 4000787029504 bytes, 7814037167 sectors
Disk model: M3 Portable    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt 
Disk identifier: A06D421E-6CCD-4993-B9B7-993C3A5AE2B0

Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdd1   2048 7814035455 7814033408  3,7T Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/sdd1: 3,65 TiB, 4000785104896 bytes, 7814033408 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

```
stack@exchange:~$ sudo dmesg | tail -19 
[3043967.678351] usb 2-8: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 121 using xhci_hcd
[3043967.698757] usb 2-8: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=61b7, bcdDevice= 0.00
[3043967.698758] usb 2-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[3043967.698759] usb 2-8: Product: M3 Portable
[3043967.698760] usb 2-8: Manufacturer: Seagate
[3043967.698760] usb 2-8: SerialNumber: HQ8P1VMT
[3043967.702631] scsi host7: uas 
[3043967.703046] scsi 7:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Seagate  M3 Portable      9300 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[3043967.703490] sd 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg4 type 0
[3043967.703619] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] Spinning up disk...
[3043968.738250] .......ready
[3043974.882695] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] 7814037167 512-byte logical blocks: (4.00 TB/3.64 TiB)
[3043974.988515] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] Write Protect is off 
[3043974.988516] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] Mode Sense: 4f 00 00 00
[3043974.988656] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA 
[3043974.988839] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes
[3043975.132112]  sdd: sdd1
[3043975.155029] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] Attached SCSI disk
[3043975.771110] EXT4-fs (sdd1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
```

From here I unmounted the disk first.

```
stack@exchange:~$ sudo umount /dev/sdd
stack@exchange:~$ sudo umount /dev/sdd
umount: /dev/sdd: not mounted.
stack@exchange:~$ sudo fsck.ext4 -n /dev/sdd
e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext4: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext4: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdd

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>

Found a gpt partition table in /dev/sdd
```

```
stack@exchange:~$ sudo umount /dev/sdd1
umount: /dev/sdd: not mounted.
stack@exchange:~$ sudo fsck.ext4 -n /dev/sdd1
e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
maxtor_classes: clean, 11/244195328 files, 15606527/976754176 blocks
stack@exchange:~$
```

## Some analysis

From my research I know now that "safely remove drive" writes data from the write cache to the drive. However, in this specific case I did not perform any operations which could have caused the write cache to contain any data. Once I inserted the drive, I saw Windows explorer showing an empty list of files, then I immediately proceeded to use the "safely remove drive" button.

## Questions

- How can I recover data from this harddisk or restore the harddisk?

Comment: You can probably research the last question yourself. If it's documented you'll have that info same as we might. Please edit your question to leave a single question here.

Comment: I edited my question to leave a single question. By the way, I do not agree that I can probably research the question myself because 1) I already did and 2) that question refers to a feature in Windows which I am using in an improper or unintended manner. Therefore no official documentation of Windows is going to explain how "Safely remove drive" feature works under the hood when applied to ext4 filesystems. No offense.

Comment: It's quite odd that you say Explorer shows an "empty disk". Normally, Explorer shows nothing, and if you artificially assign a Windows drive letter to the Ext3 partition, any attempt to do anything with that drive results in a msg that disk can not be used until formatted. Do you have some software installed in Windows that purports to handle Linux filesystems? They are widely reported to cause file system corruption! The Safely Remove Drive thing is probably a red herring - there can be no cache on a filesystem that is never mounted. Suggest you use the gdisk utility to analyze/repair.

Comment: We are not Microsoft and so we cannot describe the inner functions of their systems unless they have published it. If the information is published, you have as much access I we do. If the information is not published all we have is opinion, nothing more than you do.

Comment: @kreemoweet I do have WSL2 on that Windows computer, but did not do anything with WSL. In Explorer I saw "nothing" in the file list, which pretty much comes down to an empty disk. I'm gonna look into the gdisk utility, thanks for the hint.

Comment: Since Windows doesn’t support ext4 I would imagine Windows asked you to initialize the disk. Did you initialize the disk?

Comment: @Ramhound No, Windows did not ask me to initialize the disk. On the contrary, everything went "smoothly". I believe even Windows Explorer opened by itself as usual, but I cannot remember exactly. No error messages or popups under Windows. And it did not take any longer than usual, I did not hear any strange sounds from the disk, the disk did not seem to be excessively positioning the heads etc. All went "smooth".

Comment: Windows doesn’t support ext4 so do you have software installed to support that file system?

Comment: @Ramhound No, I do not have software installed to support ext4 under Windows. The reason I am using ext4 is that I mostly use Linux nowadays.

Comment: Well then it’s impossible for File Explorer to have opened up when you connected a ext4 drive

Comment: @Ramhound : I did not say that I am 100% sure that File Explorer opened up by itself after connecting the ext4 drive. Looks like a misunderstanding.

Comment: To be frank, I can hardly **not** believe that this whole story isn't actually a result from you accidentally emptying / reformatting the drive yourself on Linux (without being aware of the fact; like you mixed up drives / working path, etc.). I've been running Windows VM that directly use the **same whole** (no raw vmdk partition masking whatsoever) drive where the Linux host resides and haven't had a single file lost. With the *partition* type `Linux filesystem` you won't be able to assign a drive letter since Windows will not see it as a valid *volume*: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V38xy.png

Comment: You may even try to insert the drive again in Windows and see if you get anything different from what I've shown. I don't even think you need to wait until you clone the drive (to avoid further writing whatsoever; since such write won't even exist). The thing is neither the ext4 nor the gpt is broken / tampered according to your pastes, so if this whole story were true, Windows will need to know how to validly update the ext4 filesystem to make all the *files* gone.

Comment: @TomYan In your screenshot I see only NTFS disks, which is different from my case. Yes, in the past I have used NTFS back and forth between Linux and Windows. A few times I had issues which were easy to recover from. A few months ago I switched to ext4. This is the first time I accidentally put an ext4 drive in Windows and then did the "Safely remove"-thingie. In the past few weeks I had no plans to format anything, except [Document File Formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_file_format), which, by the way, is a whole different topic. I am 100% certain I did not format the disk.

Comment: @TomYan I do not believe that the disk has been wiped. Besides, the whole process of plugging in, safely remove and plugging out took perhaps half a minute. That's not nearly enough to deep format a drive. That's why I believe the data is still there and something must have happened to the partition, boot sector, GPT, or something similar.

Comment: The point of that screenshot is that you'll see no *volume* for partition has type other than Microsoft basic data, and you can only delete the partition. It doesn't even matter if it was formatted with NTFS or ext4 (the *filesystem*) in that case. The fact that you completely missed the point / (the right-clicked) "Disk 1" of that screenshot makes me doubt your story even more.

Comment: And I can tell you that the chance safely remove is even relevant here is pretty much 0 without rounding down, because there's no way for it to precisely have all the *files* removed instead of breaking your partition table or filesystem, even if something is bugged in windows. That's simply illogical. I am more inclined to that you have `rm -R *` or so instead of reformatting too (at least not from CLI with some `mkfs`, because these days you need to `wipefs` first or force it or so when there's an existing filesystem, also AFAIK no `mkfs` retain filesystem label (`maxtor_classes`)).

Comment: The truth is, even if assuming this is related to an OS bug (still, hardly possible), it's way more likely, or actually, it could pretty much only be one in the Linux distro/kernel you are using.

Comment: @TomYan I do not believe that Windows has a bug which lead to this problem. I do believe that because of incompatibilities between Windows and ext4 filesystem, that "something" must have happened. You speak about file removal: I never said anything about file removal. Both Windows Explorer and Linux file managers __DISPLAY__ zero files. File display and file removal are 2 different things. A quick search on Google reveals that many people experience disappearance of files due to issues like security settings, changing partition type on-the-fly, viruses that hide files etc. No removal involved.

Comment: @TomYan Long time ago I used to have an external harddisk with a separate power cable. When I connected the harddisk using USB cable and forgot to insert the power cable, I could see Windows Explorer opening up with __exactly zero__ files. Aside from that power cable issue I never had any quarrels with that harddisk. So yes, there exist circumstances in real life where zero files can be witnessed in Windows Explorer, yet all data is safe. I hope that the issue I am facing today is also such a simple matter.

Comment: To be frank, I've never even heard of (let alone experienced) such things of "display zero files". There's the usual case "no medium" though, in which case you sort of see a drive with 0 capacity, or "a drive with no drive". The thing is what your fsck output show pretty much indicates no file (instead of "no file displayed), as it looks a lot like one (if not identical) to what you'll get on a freshly formatted ext4. I cannot rule out some virus (on the Linux side) might have all your files "hidden" -- if you have an idea what `rm` does, it kind of count as "hidden" as well

Comment: And there's no such thing as `incompatibilities between Windows and ext4 `. It just doesn't support it at all, which is why it can only have the partition formatted if the type *indicates* that it's a "Windows partition", or have the partition (entry) removed from the partition table first if not. Certainly you can zero out on *block level* as well, but hitting only blocks so that only all *files* on an ext4 are gone? Then the virus itself can be considered as some kind of ext4 driver, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Good on ya, certainly seem to have done your diligence.

This bit here though:

> e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020) ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in
> super-block fsck.ext4: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
> fsck.ext4: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open
> /dev/sdd
>
> The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid
> ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really
> contains an ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystem (and not swap or ufs or
> something else), then the superblock is corrupt, and you might try
> running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
> e2fsck -b 8193   or
> e2fsck -b 32768

Did you try with the backup blocks? `dumpe2fs` will give you a list of backup blocks to try. `e2fsck` should restore the primary with one of the backups
If for whatever reason e2fsck doesn't work, you can also mount the drive using the backup blocks, to get your data off.

`testdisk` should also be able to re-write your partition table.

Oh, and windows probably tried writing a "desktop.ini" file to the thing, or something. I can't say this enough, don't mix (anything) with windows - it doesn't play nicely with others.